# How to check whether i am creating new instances or not programmatically?

Tags: java

According to docs, The `Boolean.valueOf(boolean)` method never creates an object.

```
public class Employee {
    public static void main(String args[]){
            String s1 = "false";
            String s2 = "false";
            String s3 = "true";

            System.out.println(Boolean.valueOf(s1));                
            System.out.println(Boolean.valueOf(s2));                
            System.out.println(Boolean.valueOf(s3));                
    }
}
```

This below method translates a boolean primitive value into a Boolean object reference

```
public static Boolean valueOf(boolean b) {
    return b ? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE;
}
```

As of now how many `Boolean Objects` are created?. Can i check some where in my console whether an `new Object()` is created or only an `Object reference` alone.

Comment: Unless the docs are incorrect, why do you need to check?

Comment: You see any memory usage peak at process manager?

Comment: Compare the Booleans with `==` to Boolean.TRUE and Boolean.FALSE.

Comment: Where in the docs does it say that valueOf is _guaranteed_ to not create a new instance?

Comment: Do it millions of times, store each result, and see what is on the heap with a profiler tool - or a heap dump with jmap. Though I'd trust the JDK code on this one...

Comment: @MK.: "*If the specified boolean value is true, this method returns Boolean.TRUE; if it is false, this method returns Boolean.FALSE."* Thus no new objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not calling

```
public static Boolean valueOf(boolean b) { ... }
```

You are calling

```
public static Boolean valueOf(String s) {
    return toBoolean(s) ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```

where `toBoolean(String)` is implemented as follows:

```
private static boolean toBoolean(String name) {
    return ((name != null) && name.equalsIgnoreCase("true"));
}
```

The conclusion is: In the code you posted, no new `Boolean` objects are created at all.

---

The `Boolean` class defines two `Boolean` objects which are created when the class is first loaded:

```
public static final Boolean TRUE = new Boolean(true);
public static final Boolean FALSE = new Boolean(false);
```

Comment: "In the code you posted, no new Boolean objects are created at all, **besides** those defined in the Boolean class" is a little confusing.  In the code that the OP posted, no new Boolean objects are created at all, period, even those constants declared in the Boolean class.  Those were created when Boolean's static initializers were run, and they're just being returned here.  No Boolean objects are being created.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: Yes, I've meant what you said, your's is clearer. At runtime, 2 `Boolean` objects exist, but they are created by the `Boolean` class and not by OPs code.

Answer (score 0):

No new objects are created, you are never instantiating a new Boolean object.  By using `Boolean.valueOf()` you are just calling a reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can track number of instances using jvisualvm or any other memory profiler / analyzer tool.